# Undesired result in output file when calling function multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Context:

I'm creating a program that automatically replaces macOS application icons and I'm currently making a function to backup some information before replacing those icons.

Problem:

When I call the following function one time everything works perfectly but when I call it a second time the same information is appended to the file even though I have provided an if statement.
I can't seem to make the function "read the file and if it doesn't exist create the file then read it" as well as "append to the file if `app["app_name"]` is not in the file".

Code:

```
def backup(app_list):
    """ 
    Takes a list of dictionaries containing the "name" & "path" of each application
    Saves the original icon name for each application in a file
    """
    if not os.path.exists(BACKUP_PATH):
        os.mkdir(BACKUP_PATH)
    for app in get_icon_name(app_list):
        with open(os.path.join(BACKUP_PATH, "CFBundleIconFile.txt"), "a+") as file:
            if app["app_name"] not in file.read():
                file.write(str(app) + "\n")
```

Clarification:

The "get_icon_name" function returns a list of dictionaries containing the "app_name" & "icon_name" for each application in the given list.

Comment: try ```w+``` instead of ```a+```. You are opening for appending and reading, ie. adding to the file

Comment: Opening file in "a" or "a+" places the file pointer at the end and "read" returns nothing (empty string).

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman "w+" truncates the file on opening. It should be "r+" instead.

Comment: @MichaelButscher If I use `r+` and the file doesn't exist it won't create it.

Comment: Just do two separate operations? Read the file, and then if appropriate, re-open and appen?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I can't seem to find any character that reads a file and creates it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: If it doesn't exist already, you want it to *successfully* read the newly created file, resulting in an empty string? Or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If it doesn't exist, it will create the file and read it then it will append to it because ```app["app_name"] not in file.read()``` will be equal to True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the `seek()` method.
Using `file.seek(0)` just after opening the file in `a+` places the file pointer at the beginning of the file, allowing me to "read the file and if it doesn't exist create the file then read it" .
In order to "append to the file if the statement is True", I added `file.seek(0, 2)` after the `if app["app_name"] not in file.read()` statement which places again the file pointer to the end of the file.

Code:

```
def backup(app_list):
    """ 
    Takes a list of dictionaries containing the "name" & "path" of each application
    Saves the original icon name for each application in a file
    """
    if not os.path.exists(BACKUP_PATH):
        os.mkdir(BACKUP_PATH)
    for app in get_icon_name(app_list):
        with open(os.path.join(BACKUP_PATH, "CFBundleIconFile.txt"), "a+") as file:
            file.seek(0)
            if app["app_name"] not in file.read():
                file.seek(0, 2)
                file.write(str(app) + "\n")
```